# ReactJs select, no value displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm learing reactJs and trying to use [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

html:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="well">
                <h1>h1</h1>
                <div id="countriesSelect"></div>
                <div id="exp"></div>
                <!-- Scripts -->
                <script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
            </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Select = require('react-select');

const getOptions = (input) => {
    return fetch('//api.local/api/countries') //users/${input}.json
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((json) => {

            var data = [];
            json['data'].forEach(function(item) {
                data.push({value:item.attributes.slug,label:item.attributes.title})
            });
            return { options: data };
        });
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Select.Async
        name="countries"
        loadOptions={getOptions}
    />,
    document.getElementById('countriesSelect')
);


var options = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

ReactDOM.render(
    <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        label
        options={options}
    />,
    document.getElementById('exp')
);
```

app.js to bundle.js ->  `browserify -t [ babelify ] public/js/app.js -o public/js/bundle.js`

Result:

[image]

The problem - **when trying to select someting from dropdown**, no value shown in select. Always see the **Select...** label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are missing the value prop on the Select component and need an onChange prop as well to handle when you click a dropdown option. I highly suggest making your own select component that wraps the react-select library that way you can pass custom props and create custom functions that are used with the react-select library.

`var value;` // initialize the value variable

`function updateValue(selectVal) { 
  value = selectVal // update value variable to new value
}`

`<Select
        name="form-field-name"
        label
        value=value // set value to value 
        onChange= updateValue
        options={options}
    />`

that should get you where you need to be

Comment: I thought library already implemented the default features, like selecting value on change, if no, I don't understand the point of this library if I need to do all the stuff by my own.

Comment: The library does all the background work and providing the display. The point of having your own onchange function is so you can fit it to your own app I.E. Whatever the select Is being used for can actually change its state in your own app.

Comment: A better way of explaining is: imagine you have a form to edit or create a user. You have a select box for choosing if the user is an administrator or regular user. If you are editing a preexisting user how would react-select know what the value is currently without you passing it in. How would react-select know what is supposed to happen when you change the users role? these are the reasons you are left to manage those points